# Webkit: Encoding

Tags: html, unicode, encoding, webkit

I created a html file with gvim on Ubuntu. When I open this file on Windows with Safari or Google Chrome it's not showing é ë correctly. When I check the encoding on my windows box with vim :set encoding? it returns latin1 and on Ubuntu this returns utf-8.

Could anybody explain why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider how Chrome is supposed to know which encoding to use.

Usually, this is with an HTTP header or a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">` if you don't have control over the headers.

I imagine in your case you have neither.  If you've not set the source code encoding using e.g. magic comment headers like `# vim: set fileencoding=<encoding name>` , then the encoding your editor reports will depend on the system defaults.  And in any case, you browser won't know how to interpret that.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure that you're actually saving the file as UTF-8.
2. Is this in your `<head>`?

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   ```
3. How are you serving the file? If you're using an actual HTTP server (rather than just opening a local `.html` file) make sure to serve it with the right headers:

   ```
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
   ```

If none of these help, could you show us the actual file (even a Dropbox download link would help)?