# Different behavior on FireFox and Chrome while submit

Tags: html, google-chrome, hebrew

i am facing strange behavior.

I have java web application on tomcat 6.

The jsp files includes Hebrew letters and it works great. (client and server side).

Recently i tried to add pages for mobile and i used JQuery Mobile.

The client side is OK - i can see Hebrew,

but on the server side when using chrome - i can't get the Hebrew letters(even while decode 
it to UTF-8/ISO-8859-8/windows-1255),

when using Firefox - it works great!

i tried all combination with those 2 rows in the header:

%@page contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1255" pageEncoding="windows-1255"%

meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link previous SO question helps you out;
[Webkit: Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539608/webkit-encoding)
did you try? :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```